# Can I connect two 34" LG 34UM95-P to a Retina Macbook Pro 13?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, resolution

I have a Macbook Pro Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013 with Intel Iris Graphics. I'd like to get two [LG 34UM95-P](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34UM95-P-ultrawide-monitor) 34" 3440x1440 screens for it.

Unfortunately, LG writes that it the only compatible Mac is the 2014 new Mac Pro.

Currently I have two 27" displays with 2560x1440 resolution connected, and occasionally open the lid for a total of 9.13M pixels (at the highest interpolated resolution). But two of the LG screens would be 9.9M pixels, and over external connections as well.

I've found reports that the screen works with recent Macbook Pros, but…

- I only found ones that cover the Macbook Pro 15" with discrete graphics (and sometimes emphasize that fact)
- I want to connect two of the screens, not just one

Apple's [tech specs](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/) mention:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays, both at millions of colors

Unfortunately, the 34" screens have ~20% more pixels than that.

---

Will I be able to use two of these screens with the computer I have?

Answer (score 1):

You **ABSOLUTELY** can do this.

The statement on the box is wrong. You can use either two mini-display port to displayport cables, or two Thunderbolt cables.

My statement was based on the fact that you can (according to Apple's documentation) run two Thunderbolt monitors on that laptop, and the available resolution on the Thunderbolt cable is clearly capable of 3440x1440.

Comment: Tests in the wild show older MacBook Pro systems running multiple monitors with a total pixels of between 10.7 million and 14.6 million.  I don't have the money to buy a second 34UM95 to test, but I'd bet my final dollar that my Iris Pro late 2013 rMBP 15" would run both of them.  It runs the one I have now and the GPU never even heats up much at all.

Comment: There's one for the wish list.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-13-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html says "This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI."